# Having trouble using zipfile.ZipFile.extractall (Already read the docs)

Tags: python-3.x, zip

I have a folder with many zipfiles, most of these zipfiles contain shapefiles and some of them have subfolders which contain zipfiles that contain shapefiles. I am trying to extract everything into one main folder **wihtout keeping any folder structure**. This is where I am now;

```
    import os, zipfile

def getListOfFiles(dirName):
    # create a list of file and sub directories
    # names in the given directory
    listOfFile = os.listdir(dirName)
    allFiles = list()
    # Iterate over all the entries
    for entry in listOfFile:
        # Create full path
        fullPath = os.path.join(dirName, entry)
        # If entry is a directory then get the list of files in this directory
        if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
            allFiles = allFiles + getListOfFiles(fullPath)
        else:
            allFiles.append(fullPath)

    return allFiles


def main():
    dirName = r'C:\Users\myusername\My_Dataset'

    # Get the list of all files in directory tree at given path
    listOfFiles = getListOfFiles(dirName)

    # Print the files
    for elem in listOfFiles:
        print(elem)
        zipfile.ZipFile.extractall(elem)

    print("****************")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This script prints all the shapefiles (including the ones under subfolders). Now I need to extract all these listed shapefiles into one main folder. I try `zipfile.ZipFile.extractall(elem)` but it doesn't work.

```
line 1611, in extractall
    members = self.namelist()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'namelist'
```

Is the error I'm getting. `zipfile.ZipFile.extractall(elem)` is the line that doesn't work. I imagine it expects one zipfile but I'm trying to feed it a folder (or a list in this case?)

How would I change this script so that it extracts my listed shapefiles into a folder (preferably a new folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an instance of `ZipFile` first and use `extractall` on this instance:

```
for elem in listOfFiles:
     my_zipfile = zipfile.ZipFile(elem)
     my_zipfile.extractall()
```

Comment: hey, thanks a lot, it is working but it keeps the folder structure (if a zipfile is inside a folder which is inside another folder, it keeps this folder structure)

Is there anyway to extract all these files without keeping the folder structure? I have been told I can strip the folder path from filenames and extract like that but I couldn't achieve results. 

Thanks again for your response, appreciated!

Comment: Use `my_zipfile.extractall(path)` where `path` is the path you would your result to end up.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but it still kept the initial file structure. This solved the issue and attaching the code block that does the trick. Now I'm trying to eliminate files that don't have specific extensions.
Thank you for your input again Mike.

Answer (score 0):

I have added this code block to my script and it works now.

def getfiles(path):
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
                for name in files:
                    yield os.path.join(root, name)
        else:
            yield path

```
fromdir = r"C:\Users\username\My_Dataset\new"
for f in getfiles(fromdir):
    filename = str.split(f, '/')[-1]
    if os.path.isfile(destination + filename):
        filename = f.replace(fromdir, "", 1).replace("/", "_")
    # os.rename(f, destination+filename)
    shutil.copy2(f, r"C:\Users\username\Documents\flatten")
```